# Looking up for Column Value Existence in Different dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, join

I have 2 dataframes which has activity of users where user_id belongs to a particular user. I need to populate a new column on second dataframe based on some conditions. Here is an example

df1 is a dataframe with columns user_id and date1

```
user_id  date1
 1       2019-07-01
 2       2019-08-04
 1       2019-08-06
 3       2019-09-03
```

df2 is another dataframe with user_id and date2 as columns

```
user_id  date2
  1     2019-07-02
  1     2019-07-03
  2     2019-08-03
  3     2019-08-04
```

Both dataframe has different number of rows and for each user, multiple rows are present in both dataframes.

For each row in df2, the column 'Present_df1' needs to be populated based on equality of user_id from df1 and an inequality condition between dates, let's say date2>date1

So for each row in df2, if the combination of user_id and date2>date1 gets satisfied, we can put it as 1.

Tried the below but does not seem to work:

```
(df2.user_id.isin(df1.user_id) & df2.date2>df1.date1).astype(int)
```

I am from SQL background and there it appears little easier to visualize but in pandas I am finding it little difficult to conceptualize. Merge option produces a big cartesian product so not an good approach to think

Answer (score 0):

Note that for particular *user_id* in *df2* there can be
**multiple** rows in *df1* with matching *user_id*.

So it is to decide whether **any** or **all** of such rows have *data1 < data2*
(I assumed "any" case).

To do your task, run:

```
df2['Present_df1'] = df2.apply(lambda row:
    df1[df1.user_id.eq(row.user_id)]\
    .date1.lt(row.date2).any().astype(int), axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
   user_id      date2  Present_df1
0        1 2019-07-02            1
1        1 2019-07-03            1
2        2 2019-08-03            0
3        3 2019-08-04            0
```

If you change your mind that **all** matching rows in *df1* should
have an earlier date, change *any()* to *all()*.

Comment: Thanks @Valdi_Bo. Somehow the solution you gave above had some syntax error as it kept erroring out. However, what you gave was excellent: row operator to iterate. for id in TrainHead.index:
    
    user_id = (TrainHead.loc[[id],['user_id']].values[0])[0]
    threshold = (TrainHead.loc[[id],['AdThreshold_date']].values[0])[0]
    function(user_id,threshold) #function here just checks length of array with these two values